# Python Post request with REQUESTS/ Shiftplanning API

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I am trying to call the shiftplanning API with the following code:

```
import requests
url= "https://humanity.com/api/"
payload = {"key": "keyvalue",  "request": {    "module": "staff.login", "method": "GET","username": "myusername", "password": "mypassword"}}"
headers = {
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    } 
r = requests.post(url, data = payload
, headers= headers) 
r.text
```

I used Postman to test the api beforehand and it worked fine. The payload in the Postman code creator, however, looks like this:

```
payload = "data={\r\n  \"key\": \"keyvalue\",\r\n  \"request\": {\r\n    \"module\": \"staff.login\",\r\n    \"method\": \"GET\",\r\n    \"username\": \"myusername\",\r\n    \"password\": \mypassword\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
```

I assume, that the payload variable actually needs to be formatted as a string, as the doc at shiftplanning api says:

> Remember that any data passed to the API is to be formatted as JSON, and its string value needs to be sent via the POST HTTP request method all as the post variable 'data' (Checkout the 9th line from an example below). Also Content-Type needs to be set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

However, no matter what I do, I always get the html of the api as a return, not the json response to my http request.
Using

```
r.json()
```

doesn't do anything, except raising an error, due to the returned html.
I also tried using

```
json = payload
```

in the post request, that didn't change anything either.`

Any help and explanation is appreciated. I'd really like to understand what I am doing wrong, as it seems to be pretty straightforward to execute.

Comment: there is [Python SDK](https://www.humanity.com/api/python/)

Comment: if you get HTML then save it in file and open in web browser to see what you get. Maybe there is useful information.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The Python SDK consists auf python 2.x code, and I am trying to use 3.x. They also use urllib and not requests. Anyhow, I do not learn a lot from using sdks, so I'd like to code it myself. The html just containts the regular content that you would get when opening humanity.com/api in your browser.

Comment: using local proxy server like [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) you can see all headers, cookies, body, etc used by SDK and your code, so you can compare both and this way you can learn what wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Change `content-type` in `headers` to `application/json` if you want json response. Postman automatically sets that header for you but you need to set it in your Python code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It does not work, though. In Postman i specifically enable "content type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded" otherwise I do not get a json response. As specified in the API doc, "Content-Type needs to be set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded."